# Код Хемиинга (разбор кода java)

Tags: java, алгоритм, криптография

Изучая реализацию кода Хемминга,наткнулась на код:
с сайта http://findevelop.blogspot.ru/2012/07/java.html?showComment=1445588616804#c1926349263327219298

Возникли вопросы. 
Помогите разобраться

Никак не могу понять , для чего нам

```
private int encCharLen;--это длина строки с проверочными битами??
private boolean isHamming;--как мы задаем эту переменную??

public String encodeBytes(byte[] raw) {
    String rez = byteToBinary(raw);
    if (isHamming)//что за условие кодирования??
                  //Т.е не всегда строчка может быть закодирована?? 
    {
        rez = encode(rez);
    }
    return rez;
}



 public String encodeString(String in) {
        if (in.length()>0) {
            String rez = stringToBinary(in);
            if (isHamming) {
                rez = encode(rez);
            }
            return rez;
        } else return "";
    }
```

Метод slice Должен разрезать строку на блоки...Я не смогла разобраться как он это делает. (т.е если у нас блок длины 8 символов,он делит 1-блок на 8, 2-ой (1+2) на 16 , 3-ий на (1+2+3 блоки) 24 и.т.д???

```
private int[] slice(char[] in, int size, int part) {
int[] rez = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char curr = in[part * size + i];
    rez[i] = Character.digit(curr, 2);
}
return rez;
```

}

Реализация кода:

```
public class HammingCoder {


private int charLen;
private int encCharLen;
private boolean isHamming;

public HammingCoder() {
}

public void setHammingEnabled(boolean isHamming) {
    this.isHamming = isHamming;
}

public String encodeBytes(byte[] raw) {
    String rez = byteToBinary(raw);
    if (isHamming) {
        rez = encode(rez);
    }
    return rez;
}

public String encodeString(String in) {
    if (in.length()>0) {
        String rez = stringToBinary(in);
        if (isHamming) {
            rez = encode(rez);
        }
        return rez;
    } else return "";
}

private String encode(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] rezc = in.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < rezc.length / charLen; i++) {
        int[] c = slice(rezc, charLen, i);
        int[] cc = new int[encCharLen];
        for (int j = encCharLen - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 3 || j == 7) {
                cc[j] = (sumElem(cc, j) % 2) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
            } else if (j == 2) {
                cc[j] = c[j - 2];
            } else if (j > 3 && j < 7) {
                cc[j] = c[j - 3];
            } else if (j > 7) {
                cc[j] = c[j - 4];
            }
        }
        char[] d = new char[encCharLen];
        for (int j = 0; j < encCharLen; j++) {
            d[j] = Character.forDigit(cc[j], 2);
        }
        sb.append(d);
    }
    return sb.toString();

}

public String decodeString(String raw) {
    if (raw.length()>0) {
        if (isHamming) {
            return stringFromBinary(decode(raw));
        } else {
            return stringFromBinary(raw);
        }
    } else return "";
}

public byte[] decodeBytes(String raw) {
    if (raw.length()>0) {
        if (isHamming) {
            return byteFromBinary(decode(raw));
        } else {
            return byteFromBinary(raw);
        }
    } else return new byte[0];
}

private String decode(String raw) {
    char[] rawc = raw.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < rawc.length / encCharLen; i++) {
        int[] c = slice(rawc, encCharLen, i);
        int[] p = new int[4];
        p[0] = c[0];
        p[1] = c[1];
        p[2] = c[3];
        p[3] = c[7];
        p[0] = ((sumElem(c, 0) % 2) == 0 && p[0] == 0) || ((sumElem(c, 0) % 2) != 0 && p[0] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        p[1] = ((sumElem(c, 1) % 2) == 0 && p[1] == 0) || ((sumElem(c, 1) % 2) != 0 && p[1] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        p[2] = ((sumElem(c, 3) % 2) == 0 && p[2] == 0) || ((sumElem(c, 3) % 2) != 0 && p[2] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        p[3] = ((sumElem(c, 7) % 2) == 0 && p[3] == 0) || ((sumElem(c, 7) % 2) != 0 && p[3] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        int d = p[0] * 1 + p[1] * 2 + p[2] * 4 + p[3] * 8;
        if (d >= encCharLen) {
            d = d / 2;
        }
        if (d != 0) { // correction
            c[d] = c[d] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
        char[] r = new char[charLen];
        for (int l = 0, q = 0; l < charLen; q++) {
            if (q == 0 || q == 1 || q == 3 || q == 7) {
                continue;
            }
            r[l] = Character.forDigit(c[q], 2);
            l++;
        }
        sb.append(r);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private int sumElem(int[] arr, int f) {
    int rez = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int delim = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i <= f) {
            continue;
        } else if (count < f) {
            rez += arr[i];
            count++;
        } else if (count == f) {
            rez += arr[i];
            count++;
            delim = 0;
        } else if (delim < f) {
            delim++;
        } else if (delim == f) {
            delim++;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return rez;
}

private int[] slice(char[] in, int size, int part) {
    int[] rez = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char curr = in[part * size + i];
        rez[i] = Character.digit(curr, 2);
    }
    return rez;
}

private String byteToBinary(byte[] raw) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : raw) {

        StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
            if (((b >> bit) & 1) > 0) {
                sbb.setCharAt(7 - bit, '1');
            }
        }
        sb.append(sbb);
        charLen = 8;
        encCharLen = charLen + 4;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String stringToBinary(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
        String binstr = Integer.toBinaryString(c);
        sb.append(binstr);
        charLen = binstr.length();
        encCharLen = charLen + 4;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private byte[] byteFromBinary(String in) {
    byte[] rez = new byte[in.length() / charLen];
    int i = 0;
    while (in.length() >= charLen) {
        String slice = in.substring(0, charLen);
        in = in.substring(charLen);
        rez[i] = Byte.parseByte(slice, 2);
        i++;
    }
    return rez;
}

private String stringFromBinary(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (in.length() >= charLen) {
        String slice = in.substring(0, charLen);
        in = in.substring(charLen);
        int charCode = Integer.parseInt(slice, 2);
        sb.append(new Character((char) charCode).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Класс работает как с строками (методы encodeString и decodeString) так и с массивами байт (методы encodeBytes и decodeBytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере метода `encodeBytes`
Вызывается метод `byteToBinary` в процессе которого вычисляется `encCharLen` и далее используется в вызове `encode`. Просто передача значения из метода в метод. Не более.

`isHamming` задается с помощью метода `setHammingEnabled()`. Более того -- Так как по умолчанию **boolean** имеют значение **false**, то кодирование/декодирование не будет выполнено.

```
if (isHamming) {
    return stringFromBinary(decode(raw));
} else {
    return stringFromBinary(raw);
}
```

Чтобы включить, надо установить флаг в **true**

```
HammingCoder hc = new HammingCoder();
hc.setHammingEnabled(true);
```

Зачем понадобился такой вариант автору кода - лучше спросить у него. Скорее в угоду некоторой универсальности.

Comment: Мы получается, сразу берем кодировку 8-бит?

Comment: Метод slice должен разрезать строку на блоки...                                        Я не смогла разобраться как он это делает. (т.е если у нас блок длины 8 символов,он делит 1-блок на 8, 2-ой (1+2) на 16 , 3-ий на (1+2+3 блоки) 24 и.т.д???

`private int[] slice(char[] in, int size, int part) {
int[] rez = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char curr = in[part * size + i];
    rez[i] = Character.digit(curr, 2);
}
return rez;
}`